# CKEditor won't let me paste and save content

Tags: html, asp.net, ckeditor

I am currently trying to use CKEditor on the website that I am developing with Visual Studio's ASP.Net. The feature seems to work fine if I type everything into the CKEditor forms, but once I start pasting content from an outside source, nothing seems to work. In web developer tools with Firefox and Chrome, I get the following error when I open the edit page (even before I've typed or pasted any content):

Firefox:
[11:00:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
TypeError: t is null

I don't know what "t" is.

Chrome:
[11:08:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null

I've tried putting in break points, but I still can't determine which files the editor can not read.

On my "Edit" page, my code looks like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="JobSummary" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextArea("JobSummary", new { @id = "JobSummary" })
            <span asp-validation-for="JobSummary" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script src="~/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script>CKEDITOR.replace('JobSummary');</script>
}
```

In my bower.json file, I have this version of CKEditor:

```
"ckeditor": "4.5.10"
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a couple of days.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with Browserlink. Have you tried turning it off? http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: @Steve I tried turning of the Browserlink, but it didn't do anything. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is it possible that when you call CKEDITOR.replace(), either the CKEditor or other scripts haven't fully loaded. If you use something like jQuery, you can wrap the call in a $(function(){ /code/ }); to ensure everything is loaded.